# Brownie does not function after upgrade

Tags: solidity, python, brownie

#### What was wrong?

After upgrading Brownie from version 1.17.2 to 1.18.1, Brownie has stoped functioning properly.  Once I run commands like `brownie compile`, `brownie console`, `brownie run scripts/deploy.py`, `brownie test` it does nothing. See the following lines extracted from bash. Interestingly, old projects already built works perfectly + commands like `brownie networks` list or `brownie accounts` works as well.

What am I missing, please?

```
my_computeri@LAPTOP-VVKHNKSN MINGW64 ~/demos/aave_uni_sushi
$ brownie compile
Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

my_computer@LAPTOP-VVKHNKSN MINGW64 ~/demos/aave_uni_sushi
$
```

```
my_computer@LAPTOP-VVKHNKSN MINGW64 ~/demos/aave_uni_sushi
$ brownie console
Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

my_computer@LAPTOP-VVKHNKSN MINGW64 ~/demos/aave_uni_sushi
$
```

```
my_computer@LAPTOP-VVKHNKSN MINGW64 ~/demos/aave_uni_sushi
$ brownie run scripts/sushiswap_deploy.py
Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

my_computer@LAPTOP-VVKHNKSN MINGW64 ~/demos/aave_uni_sushi
$
```

#### Environment information

- `brownie` Version: 1.18.1
- `ganache-cli` Version: 6.12.2 (ganache-core: 2.13.2)
- `solc` Version: py-solc-x-1.1.1
- Python Version: 3.9.7
- OS: win11

Comment: Hm, it will not be probably caused by the upgrade itself. Brownie does not function anymore even though I downgraded (reinstalled/uninstalled+reinstalled) to the 1.17.2 version. Unfortunately, I do not have idea how to find out the cause thereof.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

I reinstalled brownie and brownie works smoothly again.